# How to substring a column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe

I have 2 columns in pandas dataframe YYYY and MM. I want to concatenate like YYYYMM. But problem is Mar'2019 become like 20193 and Oct'2019 become like 201910. I cannot do the sorting based on this kind of outpt. I want all month should have 2 digit like march month should be like 03, april like 04.

How to concatenate them correctly?

```
df['YYYY']=df['Order_Date'].dt.year.astype(str)
df['MM']=df['Order_Date'].dt.month.astype(str)
df['YM'] = df.YYYY + df.MM #(this does not solve problem)
```

> Expected  201903 201904 201910

actual
20193
20194
201910

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Order_Date':pd.date_range('2019-01-01', periods=5 ,freq='m')})

df['YM'] = df['Order_Date'].dt.strftime('%Y%m')
print (df)
  Order_Date      YM
0 2019-01-31  201901
1 2019-02-28  201902
2 2019-03-31  201903
3 2019-04-30  201904
4 2019-05-31  201905
```

Your solution should working with [`Series.str.zfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html):

```
df['YM'] = (df['Order_Date'].dt.year.astype(str) + 
            df['Order_Date'].dt.month.astype(str).str.zfill(2))
print (df)
  Order_Date      YM
0 2019-01-31  201901
1 2019-02-28  201902
2 2019-03-31  201903
3 2019-04-30  201904
4 2019-05-31  201905
```